# Error list plot with Errors on both variables in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, uncertainty

I am analysing some data in Mathematica for a lab report and having some trouble finding a way to plot error bars (uncertainties) on both the vertical and horizontal axes. I have imported the ErrorBarPlots function to do it. I currently have my data arranged like:

```
{{{x data point 1, ErrorBar[x error 1]},{y data point 1, ErrorBar[y error 1]}},
  {{x data point 2, ErrorBar[x error 2]},{y data point 2, ErrorBar[y error 2]}},
  etc.}
```

I can call any element of the 3d array using data[[1,1,1]] etc, but whenever I try to use the ErrorListPlot function it won't do it. I have used this function before to plot errors on only the x-axis, but am yet to be successful when plotting both.

Any tips? Is this even possible in Mathematica? Can't seem to find anything useful elsewhere on the net.

Comment: look at the example under `ErrorBar` : http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorBar.html. syntax is like `{{x1,y1,Errorbar[{dx1,dy1}]} , .. }`

Comment: Ahh, right. That makes sense. I got too caught up in trying to look for a variation on the plot function rather than the errorbar function itself. Thanks for that!